# Override Python metaclass __getitem__

Tags: python, metaclass

Given the following code, I expect a return value of `'overridden'` **not** `'value1'`:

```py
class MyMetaclass(type):
  def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
    attrs.update({'_my_dict': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}})
    return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
  def __getitem__(cls, value):
    return cls._my_dict[str(value)]


class MyBaseClass(metaclass=MyMetaclass):
  pass


class MyClass(MyBaseClass):
  @classmethod
  def __getitem__(cls, value):
    return 'overridden'


>>> MyClass['key1']
'value1'  # I expect: 'overridden'
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: Defining `__getitem__` in a class defines indexing for *instances*, not for the class itself.

Comment: `MyClass()['key1']` would return `overridden`.

Comment: Why do you expect method on the *class* to override a method on the *metaclass*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__getitem__` refers to the item-getting behaviors of the instances of the class it is defined on.

So, if you define a `__getitem__` on the metaclass, it will work for the classes - if you write a `__getitem__` on the class itself, it will only work for *instances* of that class.

You can however, write the metaclass `__getitem__` so that it calls the class' `__getitem__` if it exists - and then emulate this behavior:

```py
class MyMetaclass(type):
  def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
    attrs.update({'_my_dict': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}})
    return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
  def __getitem__(cls, value):
    for supercls in cls.__mro__:
         if "__getitem__" in supercls.__dict__:
               # getting the value straight from "__dict__" will prevent Python's mechanisms of converting it to a bound instance method:
               return supercls.__dict__["__getitem__"](cls, value)
    return cls._my_dict[str(value)]


class MyBaseClass(metaclass=MyMetaclass):
  pass


class MyClass(MyBaseClass):
  def __getitem__(cls, value):
    return 'overridden'
```

Note that in this way, you could even use any other method name for a "class_getitem" in our hierarchy and still leave the usual  `__getitem__` available to be used by instances.

Answer (score 1):

You need to subclass the metaclass, override `__getitem__` there, and set that metaclass in a new regular class.