# Is it possible to override operators (like __add__) in a Python metaclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading, metaclass

In my use case it would great if I could implement addition of classes, not their objects. Is it possible in Python? My IDE shows `__add__` as a method of `type`.
How can I override it properly?

Otherwise, I am thinking about following the dreadful [forbidden way of doing things](https://pypi.org/project/forbiddenfruit/), perhaps monkey-patching `type`.

```
class MyClass:
    def __add__(self, other):
        return "some funny result"


# Works fine!
MyClass() + MyClass()


class MyClassOperand(type):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        """Here, there will be things to instantiate the real MyClass ..."""
        # return object.__new__(cls)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return "some funny result"


# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'type'
MyClassOperand + MyClassOperand
```

Comment: You didin't *actually use your metaclass*.

Comment: yes, it is possible, and it works. I even have an example of that for a "meta meta class" - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476586/is-anyone-using-meta-meta-classes-meta-meta-meta-classes-in-python-other-lang/45873191#45873191

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60782491/9681577), this is how I did it:

```
class MyMetaClass(type):

    def __add__(self, other):
        return "some META funny result"


class MyClass(metaclass=MyMetaClass):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return "some funny result"


# Works fine: "some funny result"
print(MyClass() + MyClass())

# Works fine: "some META funny result"
print(MyClass + MyClass)
```

Answer (score 2):

it works - 
A more functional example is  simple metaclass that will create a new composed subclass of both added classes. Provided that the classes work
cooperatively, using `super()` calls, it does work with no problems at all:

```py
class Addable(type):
    def __add__(cls, other_cls):  # All metaclass methods receive classes as their "self" parameters
                                  # so they are effectively "class methods" for those
        meta = type(cls)  # this should be "Addable" itself, or a composed subclass of it
        new_cls = meta(
            f"Composed{cls.__name__}{other_cls.__name__}",
            (cls, other_cls),  # base classes
            {}, # empty namespace
        )
        return new_cls


# Example:


class Base(metaclass=Addable):
    pass

class Cls1(Base):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parameter1 = kwargs.pop("parameter1", None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def m1(self):
        print("method 1")

class Cls2(Base):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parameter2 = kwargs.pop("parameter2", None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def m2(self):
        print("method 2")

Cls3 = Cls1 + Cls2
```

And pasting that on a terminal:

```py
In [8]: Cls3().m2()                                                                              
method 2

In [9]: Cls3(parameter1 = "bla").parameter1                                                      
Out[9]: 'bla'
```